Wikipedia API: How to get article on a specific date?
I want to find a way to get the contents of a Wikipedia article on a specific date. For example, I'd like to see an article in the version it was on January 1 2022.

To do this manually or with scraping: go to the History of a page, scroll down until I find a revision that is before my desired date and click on it (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jupiter&action=history)
The REST API can retrieve the last 20 revisions (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/rest.php/v1/page/Jupiter/history)
The REST API can retrieve revisions older than another revision, but this works using a revision ID, not a date (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/rest.php/v1/page/Jupiter/history?older_than=1219856114)
Theoretically I could get the last 20 revisions, and continually ask for the previous 20, until I go far back enough in time. However, in practice that can work a few times, but because of rate limits it will not work if browing many articles within an hour

Given none of these methods work well, what is the correct way of retrieving a Wiki entry from a given date?

Use the Action API's prop=revisions instead:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php
?action=query
&format=json
&formatversion=2

&titles=Jupiter

&prop=revisions
&rvprop=timestamp|ids
&rvlimit=1
&rvstart=2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

Try it using the API sandbox.
rvstart denotes the timestamp from which MediaWiki will start enumerating, and rvlimit=1 means that we are only interested in the first revision it has to offer.
rvprop controls which data properties to be included in each revision's result; timestamp is for that revision's timestamp, and ids is for its and the previous revision's IDs.

Thanks! That does exactly what I wanted. This does not work when the page did not exist at the given date - for that edge case, do you know how to get the first revision of a page?

Found the answer: add &rvdir=newer to the query, so that the search will go the other direction
